# how to extract a particular field from json using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am creating an autocomplete component using jquery where the suggestions come from one of the fields of Solr.I am not able to extract the value from the corresponding json format.
the json file is as given and i need to extract the value of Query field.

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "q": "Query:cr*\r\n",
            "wt": "json"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 16,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [{
            "id": "90268125-f806-428c-889b-696172c55356",
            "Query": "cricket",
            "Hits": 66,
            "RespTime": 359},
        {
            "id": "d5871725-0d4f-42bc-8180-9328ed81c644",
            "Query": "cricketmania",
            "Hits": 66,
            "RespTime": 156}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "q": "Query:cr*\r\n",
            "wt": "json"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 16,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [{
            "id": "90268125-f806-428c-889b-696172c55356",
            "Query": "cricket",
            "Hits": 66,
            "RespTime": 359},
        {
            "id": "d5871725-0d4f-42bc-8180-9328ed81c644",
            "Query": "cricketmania",
            "Hits": 66,
            "RespTime": 156}]
    }
}

data.response.docs[0].Query

data.response.docs[1].Query
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GJwKp/)**

Using loop:

```
$.each(data.response.docs, function(i, val) {
  console.log(val.Query);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6CcQV/)**

You can also use simple for loop:

```
for( var key in data.response.docs ) {
   alert(data.response.docs[key].Query);
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ULm5/1/)**

Comment: I tried this and its showing me "undefined" when i am trying to print it in an alert box.

Comment: alert( data.response.docs[0].Query ); gives me [Object Object] in an alert box!

Comment: @user1438978 its working for me see http://jsfiddle.net/GJwKp/.. I think you're making some mistake, please take a close look

Comment: ya got it,i had mentioned an extra parameter in the url which was not giving me the query field.I got it done using the for loop.Thanx all :)